# javascript when promise all video loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to refactor a bad piece of code with a better $.when promise.
What I need is to wait that all videos in the page are loaded and then find the duration of the longest one.

The old code is:

```
$.each($('video'), function() {
    this.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        init_timer();
    });
});


var num_videos = $('body video').length;
var video_loaded = 0;

function init_timer() {

    video_loaded++;
    if(video_loaded >= num_videos) {
        console.log(getMaxVideoLenght());
    }   
}
```

The new one is:

```
$.when( $('video').on('loadedmetadata') )
.done(function() {
    console.log(getMaxVideoLenght());
});
```

The old one works but in the new code, the console.log print "0" because the videos are not already loaded (even with then instad of done).

Comment: Well, `on` doesn't return a promise, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`on` doesn't return a promise. You could give yourself a promise like this:

```
Promise.all($("video").map(function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $(this).one("loadedmetadata", resolve);
    });
})).then(() => {
    console.log(getMaxVideoLength());
});
```

Or if you need to stick to ES5 and use jQuery's Deferred:

```
$.when.apply($, $("video").map(function() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $(this).one("loadedmetadata", d.resolve.bind(d));
    return d.promise();
})).done(function() {
    console.log(getMaxVideoLength());
});
```

---

Side note: In the above, I fixed the spelling of `getMaxVideoLength` (it's `th`, not `ht`, at the end).

Comment: wow.. thank you.. it works perfectly!!
now I just need to understand what you write ahaha